# docker image is different when running from different host

Tags: c++, docker, gcc

During building of a 3rd party library (`libtorch`, if it matters) in a docker container, I came across an error of a missing include file.
The same process of building worked fine when running the build process from Ubuntu 16.04 host, but when running from an Ubuntu 18.04 host, the file was missing.

After a bit of trace back, I'm now just running the base container from NVidia, and looking for the file.
This is the outputs I get:

`Ubuntu 16.04 host`:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ub-carmel 4.15.0-123-generic #126~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 21 13:48:05 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d

$ docker pull  nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda:11.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04

11.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04: Pulling from nvidia/cuda
Digest: sha256:c5bf5c984998cc18a3f3a741c2bd7187ed860dc6d993b6fb402d0effb9fe6579
Status: Image is up to date for nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda:11.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04
nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda:11.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04
$ docker run -it  nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda:11.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04
root@2ecc17248fab:/# ll /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include | grep ia32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7817 Dec  4  2019 ia32intrin.h
```

`Ubuntu 18.04 host`:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ub-carmel-18-04 5.4.0-56-generic #62~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 24 10:07:50 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.14, build 5eb3275d40

$ docker pull  nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda:11.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04

11.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04: Pulling from nvidia/cuda
Digest: sha256:c5bf5c984998cc18a3f3a741c2bd7187ed860dc6d993b6fb402d0effb9fe6579
Status: Downloaded newer image for nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda:11.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04
nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda:11.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04
$ docker run -it  nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda:11.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04
root@89f771e82a51:/# ll /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include | grep ia32
root@89f771e82a51:/#
```

As you can see, the sha256 digest of the images is the same (and matches the digest from NVidia's NGC [here](https://ngc.nvidia.com/catalog/containers/nvidia:cuda/tags))

At first I thought that maybe in some hidden way the includes come from the host, but the `ia32intrin.h` file exists in both hosts

What can cause such issue?

**EDIT**

Added the `docker --version` outputs for each host. There's a difference, but I doubt this should cause such issues

**EDIT 2**

Added the output for `uname -a`

**EDIT 3**

Output of `docker version`:

`Ubuntu 16`:

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.13
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        4484c46d9d
 Built:             Wed Sep 16 17:02:59 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.13
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       4484c46d9d
  Built:            Wed Sep 16 17:01:30 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.3.7
  GitCommit:        8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

`Ubuntu 18`:

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.14
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        5eb3275d40
 Built:             Tue Dec  1 19:20:17 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.14
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       5eb3275d40
  Built:            Tue Dec  1 19:18:45 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.3.9
  GitCommit:        ea765aba0d05254012b0b9e595e995c09186427f
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

So I tested it on a different Ubuntu machines (EC2 instances) and in that case, for both 18.04 & 16.04 the file exists. so looks like it's a problem on my machine.
Any thoughts of what can cause this?

Comment: Are the hosts the same architecture? Show the `uname -a` output.

Comment: @BMitch, Thanks. Added it to the post

Comment: Looks to be the same, switch to the output of `docker version` instead of `docker --version`. The latter only shows the CLI client version, and misses the docker host itself.

Comment: @BMitch, Added that. Also, I doubt it matters but currently when using docker in 18.04, it runs as root, requiring password when using the `docker version` for example.

Comment: This rules out something like a multi-platform image, and whether you run the client as root shouldn't make a difference. I'll try reproducing this.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the host multi-arch? maybe do `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

Comment: @JaapVersteegh, both gives the same `i386` result

Comment: On my linux mint machine, which is ubuntu 20.4 based, the file is also just there, so it seems to me something funky is going on with your Ubuntu 18 machine/VM.

Comment: Yes, I just setup EC2 instances in AWS, one with 16.04 and one with 18.04 and the file exists in both, so it's definitely something local to my machine. Any thoughts on what? or what to look for? maybe some initialization script when a container is launched?

Comment: I would try to just move on. Update docker to latest: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/. Clear the image: `docker image rm nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda:11.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04` and try again..

Comment: just tried that, the problem still exists. now the `docker --version` output is `Docker version 20.10.1, build 831ebea`

Comment: If you're sure all parts of the image were cleared (make sure all containers are removed before removing images etc), then I'm out of options, sry!

Comment: I'll remove everything and then try, before resorting to a full reset as suggested by @BMitch 's answer below. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Clearing everything completely and forcing it to redownload all the layers solved it. Thank you both for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess is that the pulled layers on the Ubuntu 18.04 host are somehow corrupt. The nuclear option to clean that up is to reset docker. This will delete all images, volumes, containers, logs, networks, everything, so **backup anything you want to keep before running this:**

```
sudo -s # these commands need root
systemctl stop docker
rm -rf /var/lib/docker
systemctl start docker
exit # exit sudo
```